# Pipes vs Explicit Expressions performance issues in Sphinx

Tags: performance, sphinx

As I don't have any tables that are near comprehensive enough to test I'm posing a general performance question regarding Sphinx and Pipes/Or vs explicit permutations. In other words is there a performance difference between:

```
(A|B|C|)(1|2|3|)
```

vs

```
(A1|A2|A3|B1|B2|B3|C1|C2|C3)
```

Since at the end of the day they search for the same permutations?

Answer (score 0):

To make `(A|B|C)(1|2|3)` work you need to have min_word_len = 1 for the index, which adds to index size and may impact performance slightly.

For `(A1|A2|A3|B1|B2|B3|C1|C2|C3)` you need min_word_len = 2 which will reduce index size.

But if you already have `min_word_len = 1` than these should not impact performance.

Be sure that `(A|B|C)(1|2|3)` is searching for `(A OR B OR C) AND (1 OR 2 OR 3)` so its not always looking for adjacent words. So the better way to use is the `(A1|A2|A3|B1|B2|B3|C1|C2|C3)`.

Thanks

Comment: The A|B etc was just meant to indicate any given word/term. I'm more interested in the performance then of (Red|White|Blue)(Square|Circle|Triangle) vs (Red Square|Red Circle}Red Triangle|...|Blue Triangle). I do get if I needed them as terms I'd need add'l query parameters in this case I'm really trying to figure out if Iose any performance in the query by specifying each permutation (which gives me more control) vs constructing seemingly more efficient construction. If I have 10 terms on the left and 10 on right I have to make 100 different terms; will that impact the search time?